# How to create a crypto:PublicKey record by a string/file in Ballerina

Tags: cryptography, wso2, ballerina

I have public/private key files and I am reading them as strings. So now I want to call some crypto functions using it. For that I need to have a crypto:PublicKey record[1]. I cannot find a way to convert my string to a crypto:PublicKey in the API docs of crypto module [2] or in learn-by-example.[3] How to do this?

[1] https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/crypto/records/PublicKey.html
[2] https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/crypto/index.html
[3] https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/crypto.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `crypto:decodePublicKey` API to get the `crypto:PublicKey` by providing `crypto:KeyStore` and `string` key-alias [1].

```
crypto:KeyStore keyStore = {
    path: "/home/ballerina/keystore.p12",
    password: "keystorePassword"
};
crypto:PublicKey|crypto:Error publicKey = crypto:decodePublicKey(keyStore, "keyAlias");
```

**NOTE:** Ballerina `crypto:KeyStore` supports only `PKCS12` type. Other formats has to be converted to PKCS12 type. `PEM` file support will be added in future [2].

[1] https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/crypto/functions.html#decodePublicKey

[2] https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/13293

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I wanted is exactly which reported in [2] https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/13293 . So it is yet to be supported.